# Worker Node in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes. I have followed one document and setup master node in Kubernetes. Now I want to create a Worker node, so How can I create it? I don't know anything about to set up a worker node.

Comment: creating workers is documented as well

Comment: can you send me a link?

Comment: followed one document  !! what doc ? can you build the question to be more specific with you setup details 

refer this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/) on how to build a production grade environment.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on VMs or outside of a cloud provider then manually setting this up involves several steps.  The tool you will need is [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm/) (see documentation linked) and you will need to init the nodes and then `kubeadm join` the nodes to the master.

If you are using a cloud provider, then follow the providers documentation on how to add additional nodes.

A great guide called "[Kubernetes The Hard Way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way)" is another good resource for learning how to setup a cluster without any automated tooling.

Comment: I have installed a docker in a windows machine and enabled Kubernetes from there. I am using my kubernetes dashboard by running ```kubectl proxy``` command

Comment: @ankitthakkar you'll still need to add the nodes and kubeadm join is one of the ways to do that.

Comment: Is it possible to use kubeadm on windows? If yes, then how? Because I am using Kubernetes by enabling it from Docker for windows.